# How to disable check of modules updates in Node-RED?

Tags: node-red

Every time when Node-RED is starting too much time spends to check of modules updates. In our stateless containerization there is no sense to check updates. Could anyone know how to disable the update check to accelerate of starting process?

**EDITED:**

As @knolleary says the check process happening NOT when Node-RED is starting. The above conclusions were my mistake.

[image: Palette manager]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The check for updates is done entirely within the editor in the browser - the runtime doesn't play any part in that. So the startup time of the runtime has nothing to do with the update check.

The editor loads the palette catalog from https://catalogue.nodered.org in the background when you open it in your browser. It only does the work to compare the catalog with the list of what you have installed when you open up the palette editor. None of that should cause any start-up delays.

On what basis are you saying this is the cause of any delays you are seeing?

You can delay the palette manager entirely by setting `editorTheme.palette.editable` to `false` in your `settings.js` file.

Comment: Nick, thank you for detailed answer. As always, you helped out )
I thought that the check process happening when Node-RED is starting. Sorry for my mistake and thank you again for the spent time.